# Kinect accuracy in depth

Tags: ros, kinect, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I use a Kinect for Xbox 360. What is the accuracy of depth in the different ranges ?

Thanks for reply.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229061/kinect-accuracy-in-depth/) by [goupil35000](https://answers.ros.org/users/7096/goupil35000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2016-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here are several resources that discuss this:

- http://wiki.ros.org/openni_kinect/kinect_accuracy
- [Accuracy analysis of Kinect Depth Data](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=ACCURACY+ANALYSIS+OF+KINECT+DEPTH+DATA+&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C14&as_sdtp=)
- http://cs.stanford.edu/people/teichman/papers/rss2013.pdf (Includes raw values and a calibration technique for generating a mapping that improves accuracy throughout a single depth image)

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2